# functional principle components is retransform to original data

Tags: r, time-series, pca, functional-data-analysis

I am working with multivariate time series hourly data of five years, I use the first four years as testing set and last one year as validation set. My objective is to obtain one year hourly forecast, and also check the accuracy of the model. So, I transform my multivariate electricity price data into functional form through Fourier basis functions, then I calculate functional principle components as a dimensional reduction as choose the first six functional principle components explaining a given amount of variation, then using the corresponding functional principle scores and apply VAR model for the analysis and use the forecast function for one day a head forecast. The above method will give me  six forecast value but i need  24 hours forecast values in form of functional scores, know how i obtain the 24 hours forecast and then i revert back those forecast scores into original variables, how to generalize the result for one year and how to check the accuracy of the model also. for explaining my problems i am sharing my code

```
fdata<- function(mat){
  nb = 25 # number of basis functions for the data
  fbf = create.fourier.basis(rangeval=c(0,1), nbasis=nb) # basis for data
  args=seq(0,1,length=24)
  fdata1=Data2fd(args,y=t(mat),fbf) # functions generated from discretized y
  return(fdata1)
}
prediction.ffpe = function(fdata1){
  n = ncol(fdata1$coef)
  D = nrow(fdata1$coef)
  #center the data
  mu = mean.fd(fdata1)
  data = center.fd(fdata1)
  ffpe = fFPE(fdata1, Pmax=10)
  d.hat = ffpe[1] #order of the model
  p.hat = ffpe[2] #lag of the model
  #fPCA
  fpca = pca.fd(data,nharm=D)
  scores = fpca$scores[,1:d.hat]
  # to avoid warnings from vars predict function below
  colnames(scores) <- as.character(seq(1:d.hat))
  VAR.pre= predict(VAR(scores, p.hat), n.ahead=1, type="const")$fcst
  
}
```

the mat is my matrix of 24*1461.